# Core Data: Database migration causes duplicates

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

Few customers reported than after the core data migration, their database entries result duplicated.

We opened the databases they sent us and indeed the entries are duplicated. We restore the backup and convert again the database, but we can't reproduce the issue in the office. Migration just works.

What could be the reason of this duplication? Is it related to the structure of the model, or something else?

It's a lightweight migration using model mappings. The core data databases are based on mysql.

thanks

Comment: You don't tell how it's migrated or what it's been migrated from.  Are you looking for a prophet?

Comment: @ElTomato I wish I could find a prophet. I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After battling this for a while, the solution was pretty obvious for us. As it would only happen *very* occasionally so it was hard to find a repro (and even harder to find the reason!).

It seemed the app would sometimes crash mid-migration (for unknown reasons).

We are using deterministic file names for the `destinationURL` in `-[NSMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:...]` like `appdata.sqlite-model_version_2.3`. We weren't checking for the existence of the destination before migrating, and `NSMigrationManager` would copy directly into it regardless..so we'd get duplicates of every entity from the first (crashed) attempt, and singles of everything after that.

A few `-[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]` calls for the `.sqlite`, `.sqlite-shm` and `.sqlite-wal` before attempting migration to clean up any previous failed migration have solved the problem for us.

Comment: Great to know. We have the same issue.